# Как сделать поиск записей по ключу и региону в вк api?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

В ВК api есть метод `wall.search`, но он требует указать id пользователя или сообщества в вк. 
А мне нужно сделать поиск по ключу с указанием региона, но без указания id пользователей и пабликов.

Не особо хочется сначала получать список пользователей, а потом уже проходиться по их записям...

`search.getHints` - не подходит.

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/newsfeed.search ?

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже то что нужно)

Answer (score 1):

Поиска по региону нет. А вот искать сразу по всем пользователям можно с помощью https://vk.com/dev/newsfeed.search/ 
Но обязательно ознакомьтесь с лимитами на этот метод: https://vk.com/dev/data_limits